Sequellize app.post show Error saving QR history: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
I would like to make a post request, to save my built QR Code that I test my route to Postman. Ok,it works my QR code is saved into my database but it show this error message
Error creating QR history: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
    at QrHistoryModels.runHooks (C:\Users\A\Documents\GitHub\projects\typescript database\node_modules\.pnpm\sequelize@6.37.3_mysql2@3.11.0\node_modules\sequelize\lib\hooks.js:96:18)
    at model.save (C:\Users\A\Documents\GitHub\projects\typescript database\node_modules\.pnpm\sequelize@6.37.3_mysql2@3.11.0\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2547:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async QrHistoryModels.create (C:\Users\A\Documents\GitHub\projects\typescript database\node_modules\.pnpm\sequelize@6.37.3_mysql2@3.11.0\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1362:12)       
    at async postQrHistory (C:\Users\A\Documents\GitHub\projects\typescript database\configs\modules\saveQR.js:14:25)

This is my code
const postQrHistory = async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  const userData = await verifyToken(req);
  try {
  if (!userData) return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
  if (!data.customerName && !data.amounts) return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Please check your input values' });
  else {
      const qrHistory = await qrHistoryModel.create({
        qrType: data.body.qrBody.qrType,
        ppType : data.body.qrBody.ppType,
        ppId : data.body.qrBody.ppId,
        createdBy: userData.username,  // ใข้ username  from token
        qrCode: data.body.image,
        amounts: data.amounts,
        ref1: data.body.qrBody.ref1,
        ref2: data.body.qrBody.ref2,
        ref3: data.body.qrBody.ref3,
        token: data.token,
        customer: data.customerName,
        remark: data.remark,
        status: 'Created',
      });
      res.status(201).json({message: 'Your data is saved successfully'});
    }} catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving QR history:', error);
      res.status(500).json(error.message);
    }
  };

I use sequelize connect to sql server.
I'm doing a console.log (data) and (qrHistory) I get the data back but it still show error.
Addition : This is my sequelize model
const qrHistoryModel = sequelize.define("QrHistoryModels",
  {
    qrType: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ppType: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ppId: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    qrCode: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT('long'),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdBy: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    updatedBy: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    amounts: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ref1: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ref2: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ref3: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    token: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    customer: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    remark: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    deletedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    deletedBy: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  },
  { hooks: {} }
);

I add modelOption hooks later when I try to solve this error myself from asking ChatGPT, but it doesn't work.

Please add the model definition and hooks (if any) to the post
